# Does Matthew 22:21 mean that Christians can't be involved in politics?

Tags: john, matthew, jesus

Matthew 22:21 reads:

> They say unto him, Caesar's. Then saith he unto them, Render therefore
> unto Caesar the things which are Caesar's; and unto God the things
> that are God's.

Does that mean that we as Christians can't get involved in politics?

Comment: This verse says nothing about either being involved or not being involved.  It simply says to obey the law of land (Caesar's) and the law of God.

Comment: Rather than Matthew 22:21, you might instead ask this question about Romans 13:1–7, Titus 3:1–2, and 1 Peter 2:11–17.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The lesson here isn't really about politics; the most politically relevant conclusion I see from this passage is encouragement to obey the law.

--

**The trap**

The Pharisees & the Herodians (see verses 14 & 15) are laying a trap for Jesus by asking Him if He supports paying taxes:

- If He says yes, the Pharisees can proclaim Him a betrayer of Judaism and try to turn the people against Him
- If He says no, the Herodians can have Him arrested for opposition to Rome (in fact, this is exactly the tactic later used when Jesus is handed over to Pilate--see Luke 23:2).

--

**The impactful lesson**

Jesus not only foils the trap, but teaches those well-versed in the Old Testament a valuable lesson. The tribute money bears Caesar's image and should therefore be given to Caesar. I suggest Jesus had this passage in mind:

> And God said, Let us make man in our image (Genesis 1:26a)

Those made in God's image should give themselves to God.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.

Comment: +1 in a sense, Jesus beat them at their own game.  They insisted that the Temple offering be in Hebrew money, not Roman money.  So, Jesus said use Roman money to pay Roman taxes,